# How can I import TypeScript AMD modules without making the dependent code a module

Tags: google-chrome-extension, requirejs, typescript, amd

I have a Chrome extension content script that has 2 AMD dependencies. The script works fine when I load the dependencies using the requirejs "require" function.

I ported the script to TypeScript with the rest of my project, and am now using

import Dependency = require("Dependency");

which is all fine and dandy, the modules have been ported to TS and are working fine in other parts of the project.

My issue is that as soon as I add an import statement, the TS compiler wants to make my script into a module, and in the generated JS it imports the modules using requirejs "define". My chrome extension is not too thrilled about this, and when I run it I get a "mismatched anonymous define" error.

Is there any way to get the typescript compiler to use the require function to load my modules instead of making my script a module? I'm having difficulty finding anything about this.

Comment: Downvoter should post a comment as to their thoughts. This is actually a very good question with a non-obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to actually compile with the `commonjs` flag and use the fact that the TypeScript compiler doesn't actually emit `require` statements if the module import isn't used in a value position. This is similar to the "optional module loading" advanced scenario documented in the [Modules in TypeScript](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript) page.

Sample code:

```
declare var require: any; // If needed
import _a = require('Dependency');
import _b = require('SomeOtherDependency');

var a: typeof _a = require('Dependency');
var b: typeof _b = require('SomeOtherDependency');

// Use 'a' and 'b' in your code. Do not use _a or _b.
a.doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With the way my project is set up I'd rather stick to AMD, so this doesn't quite solve my problem, but is certainly useful info. It's kind of a short procedural script, so I may just leave it as a JS file for now, or worst case point the manifest to a js file that loads it. This is just a small side project, and I plan on switching over to ES6 modules once they're supported, so it's not a big deal.