# Mismatched anonymous define() in Chrome extension content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, requirejs, typescript

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension with TypeScript.
The setup is quite simple:

In `manifest.json`

```
{   
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/*"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
     {
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
        "js": [ "scripts/require.js", "scripts/require-cs.js",
                "scripts/main.js", "scripts/contentscript.js" ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true
     }],
}
```

In `model.ts`:

```
export class WebPage
{
    private id: number;
    private processed: boolean;

    get Id() { return this.id; }
    set Id(value: number) { this.id = value };

    get Processed() { return this.processed; }
    set Processed(value: boolean) { this.processed = value };

    constructor(id: number)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.processed = false;
    }
}
```

When compiled the resulting JavaScript starts with:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    var WebPage = (function () 
    {
           //Code omitted to keep the SO question short
    }});
```

In `main.ts`:

```
(function ()
{
    console.log("Executing main.js");

    requirejs.config(
        {
            baseUrl: "scripts", paths: { "model" : "model" }
        });
})();
```

In `contentscript.ts`:

```
import model = require("model");

console.log("Processing page");
var page = new model.WebPage(1);
page.Processed = true;
console.log("Done processing page");
```

When compiled the resulting JavaScript looks like this:

```
define(["require", "exports", "model"], function (require, exports, model) {
    console.log("Processing page");
    var page = new model.WebPage(1);
    page.Processed = true;
    console.log("Done processing page");
});
```

And finally in `require-cs.js`:

```
console.log("Executing requirejs-cs.js");

require.load = function (context, moduleName, url) {

    console.log("require.load called");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL(url) + '?r=' + (new Date()).getTime(), true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log("evaluating" + url)
            eval(xhr.responseText);
            context.completeLoad(moduleName);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
};
```

Which is what I found in all the other questions related to my issue.

All of this results in the following output when loading a page:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, model) {
    console.log("Processing page");
    var page = new model.WebPage(1);
    page.Processed = true;
    console.log("Done processing page");
}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

I've read those docs, I went through a lot of similar questions on SO,
but I haven't found anything that works for me yet.
Most questions deal with JavaScript specifically,
perhaps there is something missing on the TypeScript side of things?

Note: The TypeScript compiler is configured to use AMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for the error message state:

> Be sure to load all scripts that call `define()` via the RequireJS API. Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have `define()` calls in them.

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056948/how-can-i-import-typescript-amd-modules-without-making-the-dependent-code-a-modu), it seems that if you use `import` in a type script, it will be turned into a module when compiled using AMD. So by including `"scripts/contentscript.js"` as a content script you are trying to load a module script without using the RequireJS API. You can try removing `contentscript.js` from the `content_scripts` entry in the manifest and adding the following to `main.js`:

```
requirejs(["contentscript"], function() {});
```

Comment: This does solve my problem for content scripts that are defined in the manifest, thank you. I looked at the docs but it just didn't click. Doesn't seem to work for content scripts executed from a background page, but that's for another question perhaps.